# Riak max-counter

Tags: erlang, riak, crdt, yokozuna

I'd like to implement sth like a max-counter using Riak's CRDTs to use w/ Yokozuna.
The idea I had was to have a Riak map, two counters inside it, one to be modified, then the other to be updated to the max of both in a pre-commit hook.
However, I can't seem to find a way to update a Riak map to do just that.
Any help/better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query ranges w/ Yokozuna you actually can use a set and query it as if it were a counter, that seems to work